# How to concatenate results in a string when they have the same value?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database table that I'm accessing using PHP. The table contains three columns: `id`, `name`, `group`.
Here's an example of the content of the table:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id   | name   | group                              |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | Lucy   | 1                                  |
| 2    | Jane   | 1                                  |
| 3    | Emily  | 2                                  |
| 4    | Anne   | 1                                  |
| 5    | Kim    | 3                                  |
| 6    | Carrie | 3                                  |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I access my table in PHP like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

I'd like to generate the following strings, one string per group:

> Lucy, Jane and Anne are group 1 (Lucy's id is 1, Jane's id is 2,
>   Anne's id is 4).
>
> Emily is group 2 (Emily's id is 3).
>
> Kim and Carrie
>   are group 3 (Kim's id is 5, Carrie's id is 6).

What PHP function can I use to I generate these strings automatically from the content of my table?

Comment: Strings would normally be generated in the application layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would make an SQL query such as this: `SELECT * FROM table` and on the php side you would do something along the lines of:

```php
$groups = [];
foreach($data as $row) {
   if(!isset($groups[$row['group']]))
      $groups[$row['group']] = [];
   $groups[$row['group']][] = $row;
}
foreach($groups as $groupId => $users) {
    $out = "(".implode(", ", array_map(function($user) {
        return $user['name']."'s id is ".$user['id'];
    }, $users)).")";
    if(count($users) === 1)
        $out = $users[0]['name']." is group ".$groupId." ".$out.".";
    else {
        $lastUser = array_pop($users);
        $out = implode(", ", array_map(function($user) { return $user['name']; }, $users))." and ".$lastUser['name']." are group ".$groupId." ".$out.".";
    }
    echo $out."\n";
}
```